# How to correctly use auto_increment in a query

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, loopbackjs

I'm trying to write a query that insert data in a table where the ID has auto_increment property. This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE 'esegue' (
  'IdOperazione' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  'Manager' VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  'Managed' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'TipoAzione' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'DataAzione' DATE NOT NULL);
```

Then i created this model on Loopback

```
 {
 "name": "esegue",
"base": "PersistedModel",
"idInjection": true,
"option":{
  "validateUpsert": true
},
"properties": {
"IdOperazione": {
"type": "number",
"required": true,
"generated": "true",
"id":"true"
},
 ...(then Manager, Managed, TipoAzione, DataAzione)...

  "validation": [], 
  "relations": {},
  "acls":[],
  "methods":{}
}
```

And this is the query on my code:

```
saveEsegue(Manager, Managed, TipoAzione, DataAzione) {
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/esegues' , {
methosd: 'POST',
headers: {
  Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({
"IdOperazione": IdOperazione,
"Manager": Manager,
"Managed": Managed,
"TipoAzione": TipoAzione,
"DataAzione": DataAzione
  }),
});
}
```

and i call it with the params :

```
 {this.saveEsegue (null, matricola, "First Registration", now)}
```

where the column IdOperazione has no param, so it can generate an auto_incremented ID. 
But it doesn't work, and i can't understand why.
Ialso tried passing the IdOperazione in the query param, with value 'null' or '0' but still doesn't work. the error says "IdOperazione can't be blank" or "undefined"

Comment: Just omit it altogether - or set the param as null or 0

Comment: I already tried, it says that IdOperazione can't be blank, or chan't be value:0. If i omit altogether it says "IdOperazione is not defined anywhere"

Comment: If it wasn't defined anywhere, then it wouldn't know to say that!

Comment: It says it's undefined because when i query the db it sees the column IdOperazione, doesn't get any value (even i omit it everywhere in the code), in fact the error says again ": the instance is not valid, "IdOperazione" can't be blank (value: undefined)"

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sufficiently familiar with js to advise further